# accessing data of the element which is bond to knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have bind my element with the [ko](http://knockoutjs.com/), and its working fine.

My requirement is i have that element which is bond to the ko,

Data is not available even getting like this $(elem).data()

How to get it's data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at "Using unobtrusive event handlers" on the Knockout website:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html

It sounds as though you are look for the `ko.dataFor(element)` function which returns the data that is bound against the element.